# MonoTouch Professional/Enterprise

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need some help deciding between the Professional or the Enterprise versions of Monotouch. 
I've played with the evaluation version so far but now I want to deploy something on a device.
I don't fully understand the differences between one user and one seat policy, which is the main differences between the two licenses.
I assume that the Professional(one user) license can only be used by a developer logged on an account and the Enterprise(one seat) version can be used by multiple users but in both cases on the same machine. Is this assumption correct?
Can 2 developers working on 2 different machines share the same Enterprise license?
Also what is validity of the evaluation version? When does it expire? Couldn't find any data about data. I'm curios if there's any other difference with the exception that you can't deploy your application.

Thank you.

Comment: You should contact support@xamarin.com for answers to licensing questions.

Comment: The ONLY limitation of the evaluation is that it will only run apps in the Simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the FAQ](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/177051-what-is-the-difference-between-a-professional-license-and-an-enterprise-license-);

> MonoTouch Professional and Mono for Android Professional are both licensed for use by the original user of the tools.  This means that *the first user to activate the tools is the only developer licensed to use the tools*.
>
> MonoTouch Enterprise and Mono for Android Enterprise are both seat licensed.  *Seat licensing allows the owner of the license to change the named user of the tools as developers on a project change.*

As far as I know, the evaluation version will never expire, but you will not be able to deploy or debug on a real device, only emulator testing is possible.